# "Running setup.py install for statsmodels ... error" installing using PIP

Tags: python, statsmodels

I want to install `statsmodels` but I keep getting an error

I have tried

```
pip install -U statsmodels
pip install --upgrade --no-deps statsmodels
pip install statsmodels
```

I found these codes from different sites but I keep getting the same error[I'm trying to install statsmodels through PIP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrWKE.png)

Comment: Add the complete error message here

Comment: error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\-------------------------\_arma_innovations.cp37-win32.lib" failed with exit status 1120